# How to create textbox with titanium api in a html doc

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

Hi have created a file login.html and display it using webview. However, I would like to create the text box with titanium javascript and not html tag. Can anyone give me an example on this?

Comment: why are you using html for a login?

Comment: u have any idea how to solve this prob??

Answer (score 0):

i do not believe all of the titanium functions are available in the webview.

if they are then I would suggest you use the this method

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.TextField-object